# Storing a SQL column into a java array

Tags: java, mysql, sql, arrays

I want to store a sql column into an `array` using a method in `java`

**my code:**

```
public static String[] getAirports() {
        String airport[];


        try {
            String sql = "SELECT airportname FROM luggageApp.airport";
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection connection = DatabaseManager.openConnection();
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();


            ResultSetMetaData rsmetadata = rs.getMetaData();

            int columns = rsmetadata.getColumnCount();
            airport[] = new String[columns];


            while (rs.next()) {
                for (int j = 1; j < columns; j++) {
                    airport[j] = rs.getString(j);
                }
            }

            connection.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return airport;
    }
```

**What I want:**
In a for loop I would like to add all the airport names 1 by 1 into the array so I can later on call this method to fill in a jCombobox.

Comment: I was not sure to create an int variable for the amount of cells the column airport has. So I could use this in the for loop.

Comment: `column` variable should be first defined than it should be used as it will give compile time error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like following.

```
int j=0;
while (rs.next()) {      
   airport[j] = rs.getString("airportname");// get value in airportname column
                                            // and add to array
   j++;
}
```

Instead of `array` it is better to use a `ArrayList`

Eg:

```
List<String> airPorts=new ArrayList<>();
 while (rs.next()) {      
   airPorts.add(rs.getString("airportname"));                                 
}
```

Comment: Could you explain why it is better to use an ArrayList over an array?

Comment: because The capacity of an `Array` is fixed. 
Where as,`ArrayList` can increase and decrease size dynamically.

Comment: @Mr.Goose `array` has a fixed length and you need to define the size of `array`. But you don't need to bother about the length of `ArrayList`, and no need to define it.